# Group by in Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table AssignmentMaster in that I have following columns with data

```
AssignmentID         PaidAmount     RefundAmount   UserID
1                     20               0               1
2                     10               5               1
3                     30               7               2
4                     25               0               3
5                     35               15              3
6                     10               3               1
7                     5                0               3
8                     10               0               3
```

Now I want to find out the TotalNumberofAssignment with respect to userID, i.e. result should be:

```
UserID  TotalAssignment  TotalAssignmentofRefundAmount  TotalPaidAmount TotalRefundAmount
1               3                    2                       40               8
2               1                    1                       30               7
3               4                    1                        75              15
```

How I can get above given result in MSSQL.
your any help will help me lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
   UserID,
   COUNT(AssignmentID) AS TotalAssignment,
   SUM(SIGN(RefundAmount)) AS TotalAssignmentofRefundAmount,
   SUM(PaidAmount) AS TotalPaidAmount,
   SUM(RefundAmount) AS TotalRefundAmount
FROM
   MyTable
GROUP BY
   UserID
```

Note:

`SIGN(RefundAmount)` works if RefundAmount is always >= 0.

If not, change to

```
SUM(CASE WHEN RefundAmount <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalAssignmentofRefundAmount
```

Comment: +1 for new sql keyword(SIGN) for me :) , can you you tell me how SIGN works here?    Thanks Vijendra

Comment: SIGN is the same of ABS(x) / x. When x > 0, SIGN(x) = 1. When x < 0, SIGN(x) = -1. SIGN(0) = 0.

Comment: @Vijjendra: SIGN(x) gives 0 if x= 0, -1 if x<0 , 1 if x>0. See UltraCommit's comment too

Answer (score 3):

```
Select UserID, 
       count(1) as TotalAssignment,
       sum( case when RefundAmount = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as TotalAssignmentofRefundAmount,  
       sum(PaidAmount) as TotalPaidAmount ,
       sum(RefundAmount) as TotalRefundAmount
From AssignmentMaster 
Group by UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select UserId, count (AssignmentID) as TotalAssignment,
sum(case when RefundAmount = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as TotalAssignmentofRefundAmount,
sum(PaidAmount) as TotalPaidAmound,
sum(RefundAmount) as TotalRefundAmount
from AssignmentMaster
group by UserID;
```

Comment: AFAIK, SQL Server doesn't have a `DECODE` function, that is Oracle specific syntax. You could change it to a `CASE` statement.

Comment: Also, you might want to add UserID to the select list for readability of the results.

Answer (score 1):

To show how to do this using nested SQL:

```
Select  UserTotals.UserID, UserTotals.TotalAssignment,
        Refunds.TotalAssignmentofRefundAmount, 
        UserTotals.TotalPaidAmount, UserTotals.TotalRefundAmount
From    (select     UserID, 
                    Count(AssignmentID) [TotalAssignment],
                    Sum(PaidAmount)     [TotalPaidAmount],
                    sum(RefundAmount)   [TotalRefundAmount]
                    From        @AssignmentMaster
                    Group By    UserID
        ) [UserTotals] Left Join
        (Select     UserID,
                    Count(AssignmentID) [TotalAssignmentofRefundAmount]
                    From        @AssignmentMaster
                    Where       RefundAmount > 0 
                    Group By    UserID
        ) [Refunds] On Refunds.UserID = UserTotals.UserID
```